# UICollectionView in UITableViewCell. Catch scroll event

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have design like this
[image]

So I have UITableView -> UITableViewCell and in my UITableViewCell have UICollectionView. It contains dishes
On the top, I also have cell with CollectionView with horisontal scroll. It contains categories

And I want to move categories when I Scroll dishes. I try to catch scroll event in UITableViewCell class(that contains collectionView)

```
extension ProductCollectionViewCell:UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIScrollViewDelegate{

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        startScroll()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        startScroll()
    }
        
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {    
        startScroll()    
    }
        
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == productsCollectionView && productsModel.count != 0 {
            startScroll()
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing of this event was catched=( The doesn't call. It only calls on Controller with UiTableView. How can I make it?

Comment: Why is a cell a scroll view delegate ?

Comment: I thought it should help

Comment: It can not as the cell may reused and each time you set scroll view delegate to a different cell.

Comment: so, how can I understand  displayed section  of collection View, that is inside UITableViewCell?

Comment: The scroll delegate should be in a controller which is always visible. I think it is the one with the table view. The scroll delegate method have to test from with scroll view the event comes from.

Comment: hmhmhmhm, can you provide some example? How can I see where it come from?

Comment: I think I understand your problem : the collection view does not really scroll vertically : it is the table view cell which scroll. Is it right assuming The row with the catagory’s titles in table view header ?

Comment: yes. But it is not in header. categories also in another cell. So yes, I need to change selected category, when in collectionView header shows next section

Comment: I also tried will display cell in collection view, and it also doesn't call ((

Answer (score 1):

So yes. As  [Ptit Xav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13944750/ptit-xav) Sad - it is inpossible to catch. I chenged all screen to collectionView